# Resolve this error please, ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'binance.websockets'

Tags: python, binance

```
from binance.websockets import BinanceSocketManager
bm = BinanceSocketManager(client)
```

Hello guys, I'm a beginner with Binance library. Whenever I run this on Jupyter Notebook, I get this errror.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'binance.websockets'
```

Can anyone please help me solve this, I'm trying to develop a crypto trading bot, please help me resolve it.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is no "binance.websockets" in newer versions. you can directly import the required module. like,

```
from binance import AsyncClient, DepthCacheManager, BinanceSocketManager.
```

This one worked for me.

Comment: Alright brother can you then tell me how to use websockets in newer versions for binance?

Comment: Got this sample code from documentation (https://python-binance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/websockets.html#binancesocketmanager-websocket-usage)

`from binance import BinanceSocketManager
bm = BinanceSocketManager(client)
ts = bm.trade_socket('BNBBTC')
print(await ts.recv())`

The above snippet will stream the data and I don't have much knowledge on Async. So couldn't be much of help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
pip install python-binance
```

Comment: The issue comes exactly with this package

Comment: I have already installed the binance library. Still the issue remains unresolved.